# Bootstrap 4 `col-lg-4` staying stacked on Custom Domain but not on Heroku

Tags: heroku, bootstrap-4

This is the most bizarre bug.

I have a basic bootstrap `col-lg-4` situation on my app.  It works as expected on `localhost` and on my Heroku link ([here](https://stay-sane-mom.herokuapp.com/), if you want to troubleshoot.  It's the three blog columns at the bottom of the page).

However, when you look on the custom domain name to which the Heroku site maps ([here](http://www.thestaysanemom.com/), for troubleshooting), the columns stay on top of each other regardless of page width.

I tried this both with the domain hosted by Google and with the nameservers pointed at DNSimple.  I can't transfer the domain for another 51 days because it's new, but I can't imagine that should be necessary.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?  Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: This is probably a caching bug. Try clearing your cache, at least for that site. If you're on Chrome, the easiest way to do this is to open up your devtools and long-click on the reload button, then select "clear cache and force reload".

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same behaviour whether I look at the Heroku link or the custom domain. I think the problem is that within the row you have an `<a>` tag outside of your `<div class="col-lg-4">` tag, which is interfering with the Bootstrap grid.

I copied that element from your site into [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4rL972u/), which seems to replicate the problem you're talking about. Then I moved the link inside the column div and [it seems to now give the behaviour you were looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/mw5rnb2o/6/). I hope this solves your problem!